# In JavaScript or jQuery, how do you convert a single string with three words ("abc def hij") into the url encoded format: "abc+def+hij"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, urlencode

I need to encode some strings to add to a URL.

My string contains multiple words: `"abc def hij"` (i.e. **not three separate strings but a single string with 3 words in it**).

In JavaScript or jQuery, how do you convert a string like that (`"abc def hij"`) into the encoded format: `"abc+def+hij"`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) converts the string into percent encoding.

Additionally,

> For application/x-www-form-urlencoded  (POST), per http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interac...m-content-type, spaces are to be replaced by '+', so one may wish to follow a encodeURIComponent replacement with an additional replacement of "%20" with "+".

so a simple

```
string.replace(/%20/g, "+");
```

should do.

Comment: string.replace(/\%20/g, "+"); replaces all occurances of %20

Comment: Note that `%20` is also perfectly acceptable, just a bit longer. `encodeURIComponent` uses it because it is valid in both path parts and query parts, where `+` is only a valid encoding for space in query parts.

Comment: Do you need to escape that `%`? Just `/%20/g` works for me as well.

Comment: @Marcel I wasn't sure and can't test right now; if it works for you, I'll remove it. Cheers.